# Laravel db not seeding because a Model that extends Eloquent has a constructor...?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I have a simple seeder that simply has `User::create(array(...))` but it will not seed because my base model has a constructor:

```
BaseModel extends Eloquent {

protected $local_name;

public __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->locale_name = App::getLocale();
}
```

And any model (e.g. `User`) extending the `BaseModel` will not seed properly when I give a string as a field. Say for example:

`User::create(array('id' => 1, 'foo' => 'bar'));`

The `foo` field will be `NULL` whilst the `id` field would turn out fine and store the integer. It happens to any string and only strings I give it.

Anyone know what's wrong? It doesn't matter what's in the constructor, the same thing will happen.

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your User model, or at least create(). Also, "seeding" is a very specific concept in Laravel.  Are you talking about seeding a table/db, or creating a new model?

Comment: The user is simply the one supplied out of the box. Yes I'm referring to seeding a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor must have an `$attributes` array set as default:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    public function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP newbie here, should I always set `$attributes` in every constructor or only just for Eloquent?

Comment: You are extending eloquent and that is why, you also implement to model (and the contracts related with it -Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-). That is why, you have to have that in your cunstruct method.